# Get returned JSON from server

Tags: android, json

I'm uploading an image from Android app to server and as a response from server I'm sending JSON values.

How can I get that JSON in my app?

```
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
            ...
            File file = new File(path);

            if (file.isFile()) {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    URL url = new URL("http://something.com/upload.php");

                    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("File", path);

                    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());

                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + path + "\"" + lineEnd);

                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {
                        dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }

                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    serverResponseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dataOutputStream.flush();
                    dataOutputStream.close();

                }
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Usually when I use `httpClient` I read it with

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("utf-8")), 8);
String line;
jsonValue = "";

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   jsonValue += line;
}

jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonValue);
```

Comment: If you wana be programmer then you have to learn how to divide one big problem to little ones. Like: *Get returned JSON from server* is: 1. do request 2. read response (prolly stream) 3. convert stream to to string. 4. parse string as JSON ... 1. seems like you had it alread ... 2. do internet search how to get stream response with `HttpURLConnection` 3. seems like you had this code 4. do internet search ...

Comment: Off-topic comment: your copy `fileInputStream` to `dataOutputStream` code is scary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following code to read the response/error from the **HttpUrlConnection**

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    ...
    File file = new File(path);

    if (file.isFile()) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            URL url = new URL("http://something.com/upload.php");

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("File", path);

            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + path + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(serverResponseCode!=200{
                //error occurred
                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(
                        httpURLConnection.getErrorStream()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                String errorString=sb.toString();
            }else{
                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(
                        connection.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                String response=sb.toString();
                Log.d(TAG,sb.toString());
                in.close();
            }

            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
            //do whatever you wish to do with the error/response string then

        }
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
```

However, I'd advice you to use either [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [Retrofit](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) as your Http Client as they offer a lot of additional advantages over HttpUrlConnection and AsyncTask. I personally prefer Retrofit 2 as it gives me tonnes of advantages including caching, multipart upload/download, logging along with faster response

Comment: Hi. I tried your code but `String response` is empty.

Comment: Did you try replicating the request using Postman? Are you sure you're getting the response?